# How can I set new value for preference object javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, preference

```
var objectA = {x: 10, y: 10};
var objectB = objectA;

    objectB.x = 100;
    objectB.y = 100;
    console.log(objectA) => {x: 100, y: 100}

    but:
    objectB = null;
    console.log(objbectA) => {x: 10, y: 10} // Not null
```

how can I set `objectA = null` through `objectB`?

Comment: You cannot. Objects are linked through references. So changes in 1 affects other. But when you do `objectB = null`, you are replacing this reference. Hence the link is broken.

Comment: What you ask is simply impossible.

Comment: Just for reference(lol) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)

Answer (score 0):

When you do var objectB = objectA, you're only copying the reference and not the actual value. That is why when you set objectB to null, it is set to null but the reference in ObjectA still remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. When the object is allocated in memory, it stays there until gets freed. In your case, both variables points to the same memory location. There is no way to make it become null, however you call a method of this object, that will clear the values:

```
var objectA = {x: 10, y: 10, clear: function() { this.x = 0; this.y = 0; }};
var objectB = objectA;

objectB.x = 100;
objectB.y = 100;
console.log(objectA) => {x: 100, y: 100}


objectB.clear();
console.log(objbectA) => {x: 0, y: 0}
console.log(objbectB) => {x: 0, y: 0}
```